# How to pull data from URL into form with Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, autofill

I have a form where users can fill to share design work. However fields are pretty similar to dribbble.com .

I see some websites allow user to paste a link that auto fills the form. Example can be seen at https://www.uplabs.com/submit

I dont need the exact codes on how to do this. Can you please advise a direction? some plugins, some examples, ...?

Example; filling form (image, title, designer id, description, etc.) from link a link like https://dribbble.com/shots/1902343-Subscribe-to-our-newsletters

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean have something like `https://{your-url-here}}/?first_name=john&last_name=smith` would fill in the first name and last name inputs on your form?

Comment: Hi @wholevinski I just edited the question with screenshot. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand still... is this part of the URL pulling in the form data? `1902343-Subscribe-to-our-newsletters`

Comment: @Designer what kind of fields do you want to grap from the link? Title of the website and description from meta tags?

Comment: post at the given url has the data, I want to pull it and auto fill the form in my website. a perfect working example to this can be seen at https://www.uplabs.com/submit

Comment: @mario199 Let's say title and description for now. Once I figure out how to pull, I can pull anything :) I'm just curious what is the way of doing this. thank you

Comment: You mean scraping a web page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using using Ajax call to a Rails controller.
Create a rails controller which will scrap from the webpage title and meta description. You can use mechanize like in the example below.

Then using Ajax call send pasted url to that rails controller action and there perform scrapping

```
$("#url_input").on("paste", function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/url_data_grabber/grab",
    data: $("#url_input").val(),
    success: function(result) {
      $("#title").val(result["title"]);
      $("#title").val(result["description"]);
    }
  });
});




require 'mechanize'
class UrlGrabberController < ApplicationController
  def grab
    pasted_url = params.fetch("pasted_url")
    page = agent.get(pasted_url)
    title = page.title

    node = page.at("head meta[name='description']")
    description = node["content"]

    render json: {title: title, description: description}
  end
end
```