# Rails 5/Ruby - Pull og:data from external URL to populate form fields when link is pasted

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form that allows users to create a new post. The first field is a url field. I want the user to be able to paste an external url and then it pre-populate the form below with an image/title/description from the external url's open graph/meta data. Basically the same way a 'share card' is generated when you post a URL to facebook.

I've basically copied what is stated in this answer but its not working:
[How to pull data from URL into form with Ruby on Rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350502/how-to-pull-data-from-url-into-form-with-ruby-on-rails-5)

I'm struggling to figure out how to resolve it and also how to add the image (I'm using paperclip gem). Here's what I've got so far

**url_grabber_controller.erb**

```
require 'mechanize'
class UrlGrabberController < ApplicationController
    def grab
        pasted_url = params.fetch("pasted_url")
        page = agent.get(pasted_url)
        title = page.title
        node = page.at("head meta[name='description']")
        description = node["content"]
        render json: {title: title, description: description}
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
// Form Fields

<script>
$("#link_url").on("paste", function(e) {
 $.ajax({
  url: "/url-grabber/grab",
  data: $("#link_url").val(),
  success: function(result) {
    $("#title").val(result["title"]);
    $("#description").val(result["description"]);
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "url-grabber/grab" => "url_grabber#grab"
end
```

Help is greatly  appreciated!

Comment: You copied an answer that was not accepted and has no upvotes. What makes you think it works :-). You have even copied an obvious error (setting title and description on the same place). Anyway, it might work. Have you confirmed the ajax is executed? Have you verified the params received in the controller when pasting the url? What is `agent` in the controller?

Comment: Hey @Pablo 

I copied because I can't find an answer anywhere else so its the only starting point I've got.

The ajax script is being executed but I'm getting an error at the URL.

I'm not sure what agent is. I'm very new to Rails (and back end in general) so not sure exactly whats happening in the above

Comment: Please post any error you see in the browser console and in rails logs, and if the grab method is executed, include the params received.

Comment: When I paste the URL I get this error:
`GET http://localhost:3000/url-grabber/grab 400 (Bad Request)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved this using the Nokogiri gem. This provides a working solution but for a complete solution it needs fallback methods for sites with no og properties.

**fetch_url_controller.erb**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class FetchUrlController < ApplicationController
  def grab
    url = params.fetch("url")
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    title = doc.at('meta[property="og:title"]')['content']
    description = doc.at('meta[property="og:description"]')['content']
    img_url = doc.at('meta[property="og:image"]')['content']

    render json: {title: title, description: description, image: img_url}
  end
end
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#link_url').on('input', function(e) {
  var url = $('#link_url').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/fetch-url/grab?url="+url,
      success: function(result) {
      $('.js-share-data').html('<h1>'+result["title"]+'</h1><p>'+result["description"]+'</p><img src="'+result["image"]+'">');
  }
  });
});
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "fetch-url/grab" => "fetch_url#grab"
```